Condensing HTTP headers and maintaining security
When serving the majority of my HTTPS pages, I have these HTTP headers included in the response (to the browser):
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=77777777
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

The problem, they can be an overkill for small assets such as the file robots.txt. My robots.txt file now is sitting at 55 bytes (and 71 bytes when gzipped. pretty strange).
So to cut down on size, I removed the above header for robots.txt and sitemap.xml and for robots.txt the total network payload went down from about 1.2KB to 321 bytes (about an 80% savings).
So what I'd like to know is, are there short-form headers I could use to replace the headers above that would be compatible with today's web browsers?
I did think about injecting the headers into my HTML with meta-http equiv but some headers injected that way may come with a price I think.
Someone guide me. My end goal is to reduce the grand total payload (so people need to use much less data to load the web page).

May I ask why data is at such a premium in this scenario? People typically start with optimizing images and scripts; it's not particularly common for someone to look at removing headers to save hundreds of bytes over the wire.

I optimized everything else under the sun and I'm not ranking high enough so I figure if I cut down on the bandwidth I might rank better

I'm highly skeptical that optimizing headers to this degree could affect ranking at all. I would focus on the tips in the post What are the best ways to improve a site's position in Google?.

To answer your question about short-form headers, though, there is no such thing. Headers get compressed by the QPACK (HTTP/3) or HPACK (HTTP/2) algorithm, which includes a static dictionary of commonly used headers along with a dynamic dictionary of headers used during the client's connection with your site. The dictionary has a similar end-effect to "caching" your site's unique headers as the user encounters them.

What Maximillian wrote above is 100% spot on.
There’s no such thing as a "compressed format" for headers — you either use them, or you don’t.
If you want to lighten the load for your sitemap and robots, you can try using meta-http equiv, but some of your headers won’t work this way (like Strict-Transport-Security or X-Frame-Options), and others might not be as effective, like X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, since it gets initialized when the page is already loading, not before.
And as already mentioned, this is not a ranking factor at all.
